# How to access a let statement in a UIView from my main View Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, viewcontroller, uitapgesturerecognizer

Within the viewdidload in my my main ViewController I created a let statement so I can enable a tap feature.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tap(_:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer) }
```

In a separate view I'd like to disable this let statement:

```
tapRecognizer.isenabled = false
```

What's the easiest way to access the 'tapRecognizer' from my main ViewController without using a segue as the second view is a UIView so I don't think I can access it this way.

Comment: This is what instance variable/properties are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `tapRecognizer` instance variable so it can be accessible in any method or out of the view Controller if it's currently presented

```
var tapRecognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer!
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tap(_:)))
   self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer) 
 }
```

Comment: It probably makes sense to declare `tapRecognizer` as implicitly unwrapped instead of optional in this case.

Comment: Declaring a global variable isn't necessarily the best solution, as all view controllers can access and modify it, which can get confusing if you are working with a big team.

Comment: I agree but it may be needed for a delegate issue

Comment: Point of clarification: Make the variable `tapRecognizer` an **instance** variable, not a **global** variable (declare it inside the braces that define the view controller's class.) As @vadian says, making it a global is probably not a good idea. Your answer appears to be showing it as an instance variable. I think you may just be using the wrong word.

Comment: Yes , i meant instance , sorry it's a typo

Comment: And you need to add `!` to the end of the declaration or you need to initialize `tapRecognizer` in all of the `init...` methods.